# How to set theme in AlertDialog in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I've been looking for about an hour and a half, but I can't figure it out. I do NOT want to set a custom theme. I want to set a theme that is built into android for an AlertDialog.

According to d.android.com I can do this:

```
public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context)
```

or this

```
public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context, int theme)
```

So I do this and it works perfectly:

```
AlertDialog action_btn = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).create();
```

But, when I need to add a theme I get an error from eclipse:

```
AlertDialog action_btn = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL).create();
```

I am still very new to programming if someone could help me out on how to set a theme it'd be appreciated.

I also have a bonus question:

I can't get just `AlertDialog()` to work, to make it work I need to type `AlertDialog.Builder()`, but on the developer website they both seem to have the same methods and constructors. What's the difference/why doesn't `AlertDialog()` just work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Themes for the AlertDialog.Builder are only available for Android 3.0 and newer (API level 11). It seems you are have set an earlier Android version in your project settings.

The Android references show the API level of all constructors and methods. You can even set a filter to show you only the methods available for your API level.

[Read more about API levels here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)

Comment: Ugh. I can't believe it. I saw that it said "Since API Level !" so I thought everything was valid, but if you scroll down about 1/3 of the page it does say that it is only valid in "API Level 11". Thanks. Such a simple solution.

Answer (score 12):

Wrap the theme into the context, this is available since API level 1.

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(
    this,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog));
```

Comment: If you are looking for a solution for dialog styles when using API lower than API 11, here it is